# setup email connection in java

Tags: java, email, session, properties

I am trying to make connection to the email server using property files and session store value. and all the parameters are given dynamically.
this is what i'm trying

```
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailHost);
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "2525");
  Session sessions = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
  Store store = sessions.getStore(emailAccType);
  store.connect(emailHost, emailId, emailPwd);
```

Even if i am giving the correct email and password, the connection is not setting up.

please do the needful help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1. make sure the email server does not require pop3 login first.
2. make sure port is open in firewall

Do you get any exceptions during your tries?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the email server which 'm using needs pop3 login. so what i need to do to resolve this.

Comment: If you are using pop3 than maybe you need to use different properties because you are setting mail.smtp.*. Maybe this can help http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_pop3_servers.htm

Comment: this code 'll work fine for windows server but not for linux server,and what 'll be the configuration for pop.zoho.com . i am not able to establish connection. please help me out. in setting the mail connection

Answer (score 0):

Does it throw an exception or it just doesn't work?
I am using gmail for sending emails and I used something like this:

```
Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(email, password);
        }
    });
```